# Javascript redirect causing a security exception in asp.net 4.0 forms

Tags: javascript, asp.net

As part of my current project I have had to make a page take on two functions due to some functional limitations.

At present the two views are turned on and off based on a query string value. The page is loaded from an menu that is similar to that of the original ipods and as such uses Javascript to kick things off.

The problem is when I select my url (along with the query string value) I get a potential security risk error. I believe that its down to security not allowing Javascript to redirect with the query string, however I am at a loss as to how we solve this one.

The error reads -- 'A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?).'

I know that I can turn the security off on the page, however this is not an option in this instance.

Any ideas would be greatly recieved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the offending code/URL

Comment: URL should read .../default.aspx?searchType=AwaitingApprovalBulk. I notice that when it is shown in the browser address bar I get ..../default.aspx%3FsearchType=AwaitingApprovalBulk. If the first link is type directly into the browser then it is fine and takes me where I need to go.

Comment: I think you need to URLDECODE the URL.

Comment: Yes. Is the error coming from the app or from the browser?

Comment: Application error -- System.Web.HttpException:

Answer (score 0):

Without code or the link, my best guess is you probably need to urlencode the href. If there are certain characters in the URL, such as <> or an extra ?, then .net throws this error. The javascript isn't the issue, the value of the URL is. It would do this even if you typed the URL in manually.

Comment: Diodeus is onto it, you need to urldecode the href. 

    location.href = unescape(link);